# Extracting indirect quotations

Tags: nlp

I found [`textacy`](https://github.com/chartbeat-labs/textacy) Python library, built on top of Spacy, a useful tool to experiment with direct quotation extraction. Unfortunately, `textacy` that does not support extraction of indirect quotation (according to this [issue](https://github.com/chartbeat-labs/textacy/issues/293)). So far, I have used rule-based approach that looks for reporting verb and its open clausal complement. However, this is quite custom and home-made solution.

Is there a library, preferably in Python, for such a task?